# Google Analytics goal funnel does not recognize virtual page views

Tags: google-analytics

I have a setup wizard with 3 steps.  Since I'm using AJAX each step uses a virtual pageview with an appropriate URL for each step (see below).  The pageviews are being recorded in the Content section of Google Analytics but the Goal Funnel still shows zero for each step.

I've tried advise on other forums such as...

- Make sure Goal URL is set to Exact match
- Make sure no steps or the Goal URL are a parent directory of any other steps. For example, don't track /wizard/ as a Goal/step and track /wizard/step2/. Not sure why this would be a problem since it is an exact match, but it shouldn't hurt so I tried it...
- Require (or don't require - tried both) the first step in the funnel

...but none of these seem to work. Thoughts?

---

### Goal Settings

Exact match : "/wizard/setup-complete/"

Funnel
Step 1 : "/wizard/step1/"
Step 2 : "/wizard/step2/"
Step 3 : "/wizard/step3/"

Comment: (Given that by now you've waited at least 48 hours for new results to be logged - please check if you haven't) Are there any events or page views being sent in-between those steps?

Comment: Yes, pageviews and events have both been logged...

Answer (score 2):

Found the a clue answer on a help forum:  http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1116091

The match type you select for the Goal URL also applies to any URL in the Funnels section.